# Summarize columns in crosstab in percentage structure of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such problem:
This is file: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/
I ought to summarize columns in precentage structure of columns but I can't. I get only sum of rows.
I do such code:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df.make, columns=df.body_style, normalize='columns',margins=True).applymap('{:.2f}%'.format)
```

I get only this:
[image]

I need summarized of columns, not rows

Comment: Hi! Would mind explaining a bit better what `summarize` means? Can you also post a [mcve], i.e. including your input and expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `normalize='index'` parameter:

```
df = pd.crosstab(index=df.make, columns=df.body_style, normalize='index')
df['All'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)

body_style     convertible   hardtop  hatchback     sedan     wagon  All
make                                                                    
alfa-romero       0.666667  0.000000   0.333333  0.000000  0.000000  1.0
audi              0.000000  0.000000   0.142857  0.714286  0.142857  1.0
bmw               0.000000  0.000000   0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  1.0
chevrolet         0.000000  0.000000   0.666667  0.333333  0.000000  1.0
dodge             0.000000  0.000000   0.555556  0.333333  0.111111  1.0
honda             0.000000  0.000000   0.538462  0.384615  0.076923  1.0
isuzu             0.000000  0.000000   0.250000  0.750000  0.000000  1.0
jaguar            0.000000  0.000000   0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  1.0
mazda             0.000000  0.000000   0.588235  0.411765  0.000000  1.0
mercedes-benz     0.125000  0.250000   0.000000  0.500000  0.125000  1.0
mercury           0.000000  0.000000   1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.0
mitsubishi        0.000000  0.000000   0.692308  0.307692  0.000000  1.0
nissan            0.000000  0.055556   0.277778  0.500000  0.166667  1.0
peugot            0.000000  0.000000   0.000000  0.636364  0.363636  1.0
plymouth          0.000000  0.000000   0.571429  0.285714  0.142857  1.0
porsche           0.200000  0.400000   0.400000  0.000000  0.000000  1.0
renault           0.000000  0.000000   0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  1.0
saab              0.000000  0.000000   0.500000  0.500000  0.000000  1.0
subaru            0.000000  0.000000   0.250000  0.416667  0.333333  1.0
toyota            0.031250  0.093750   0.437500  0.312500  0.125000  1.0
volkswagen        0.083333  0.000000   0.083333  0.750000  0.083333  1.0
volvo             0.000000  0.000000   0.000000  0.727273  0.272727  1.0
```

Or:

```
df = pd.crosstab(index=df.make, columns=df.body_style, normalize='columns')
df.loc['All'] = df.sum(axis=0)
print (df)

body_style     convertible  hardtop  hatchback     sedan  wagon
make                                                           
alfa-romero       0.333333    0.000   0.014286  0.000000   0.00
audi              0.000000    0.000   0.014286  0.052083   0.04
bmw               0.000000    0.000   0.000000  0.083333   0.00
chevrolet         0.000000    0.000   0.028571  0.010417   0.00
dodge             0.000000    0.000   0.071429  0.031250   0.04
honda             0.000000    0.000   0.100000  0.052083   0.04
isuzu             0.000000    0.000   0.014286  0.031250   0.00
jaguar            0.000000    0.000   0.000000  0.031250   0.00
mazda             0.000000    0.000   0.142857  0.072917   0.00
mercedes-benz     0.166667    0.250   0.000000  0.041667   0.04
mercury           0.000000    0.000   0.014286  0.000000   0.00
mitsubishi        0.000000    0.000   0.128571  0.041667   0.00
nissan            0.000000    0.125   0.071429  0.093750   0.12
peugot            0.000000    0.000   0.000000  0.072917   0.16
plymouth          0.000000    0.000   0.057143  0.020833   0.04
porsche           0.166667    0.250   0.028571  0.000000   0.00
renault           0.000000    0.000   0.014286  0.000000   0.04
saab              0.000000    0.000   0.042857  0.031250   0.00
subaru            0.000000    0.000   0.042857  0.052083   0.16
toyota            0.166667    0.375   0.200000  0.104167   0.16
volkswagen        0.166667    0.000   0.014286  0.093750   0.04
volvo             0.000000    0.000   0.000000  0.083333   0.12
All               1.000000    1.000   1.000000  1.000000   1.00
```

Comment: I know normalize = index, that give me overall percentage structure. I need normalize='columns' to make percentage for each columns. Because I need sum of each columns: 100%

Comment: @WojciechMoszczyński - Not sure if understand, rather edited answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanx :-)